# how to update app xibs which are sized programmatically be converted to iphone x

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an app which is made programmatically, no auto-layout. The app consists of `xibs`. Now I want to make it iPhone X compatible. I have added launch storyboard to make it iPhone X compatible but the view and its objects were completely distorted.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is no easy fix. Either convert your app to use autolayout or make the code changes to deal with iPhone X size

Comment: why no auto layouts?

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing this in this way I check if the device is iPhone x if its true I made changes accordingly...

```
func checkIfIphoneX() -> Bool{
    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 1136:
                print("iPhone 5 or 5S or 5C")
                return false
            case 1334:
                print("iPhone 6/6S/7/8")
                return false
            case 1920, 2208:
                print("iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+")
                return false
            case 2436:
                print("iPhone X")
                 return true
            default:
                print("unknown")
                return false
            }
    } else {
        return false
    }

}
```